# How to prevent '+' operator from concatenating rather than summing

Tags: qgis, expression, summarizing, syntax, concatenation

I am trying to sum two fields and am using the expression below.

```
"Q1 answer" + "Q2 answer"
```

This expression is concatenating the answer to `'32'` when the answer should be `'5'` (3 plus 2)

I have tried changing the attribute fields from string to number. Sorry if this is a simple fix! I have tried everything I can think of. All the other operators seem to work (-, * / etc.).

Using QGIS version 3.22.5

Comment: I have tried making the attribute field text and number - the same thing happens. I am using the value map widget to choose an answer which is 1, 2, or 3 with a description 'good', 'moderate' or 'poor'.

Answer (score 4):

I think this should cover most situations:

C=`coalesce(try(to_real( "A" ), 0), 0) + coalesce(try(to_real( "B" ), 0), 0)`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your attributes to integer values with `to_int()`:

```
to_int ("Q1 answer") + to_int ("Q2 answer")
```

This is to get integer values. Or use `to_real()` for decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

OK I have answered my own question, Sorry BERA. Once I SAVED the layer the sum appears rather than the two numbers as in '5' instead of '32'.

I wasn't saving it because the correct answer was not appearing in either the preview or the attribute form cell once the expression was applied. This seems like a strange glitch.

Thanks for looking at my question!